# Sudden shutdowns on Ubuntu 18.04 Acer Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, laptop

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on an Acer Laptop (F5-573G-52PJ).

Randomly the system does a shutdown itself.
In /var/log/syslog I see the events:

```
May 15 11:24:53 top boltd[1176]: power: got event for guard '2' (10)                               
May 15 11:24:53 top boltd[1176]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' deactivated                          
May 15 11:24:53 top boltd[1176]: power: shutdown scheduled (T-20,00s)                              
May 15 11:25:13 top boltd[1176]: power: setting force_power to OFF
```

In the second before, I started a Terminal. In other occasions I didn't.
It also only happens if the laptop is running on batterypower.
Has someone experieced similiar things?
Thanks for your inputs and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems fixed in Ubuntu 20.04? I was having restarts with 19.10, but almost two days now on 20.04 and all is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Lenovo L580+Ubuntu 18.04, the laptop would turn off when I was talking by Skype. This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove bolt
```

Comment: can you explain why that worked? what is the issue with `bolt`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Reinstalled Ubuntu a few days ago. The bug occured no more but a few days later, it started to happen again :( I don't know why.
But I know that it has something to do with power management of the thunderbolt chip.

I didn't find a solution but at least two workarounds:

- simply connect a random thunderbolt device (this workaround is quite annoying)
- type `boltctl power` in a terminal and do not abort it.
  Then the output of `boltctl power -q` should output something like this:

  ```
  supported: yes
  power state: on
  1 active power guards:
    guard '1'
     ├─ who: boltctl
     └─ pid: 4311
  ```

EDIT:
Seems like this bug is the same: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bolt/bolt/issues/146#note_170316

Comment: Do you know why the second work around (`boltcl power`) works? I can confirm that it does work, but I'd like to understand why.